# Pdf file disappears after downloading from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload pdf file to firebase storage. After uploading the file,it must download the same file from the storage and display it in the pdf view.The problem is as soon as I press the back button and come back again to view the file it disappears from the pdf view. This is the code I am using:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
             final StorageReference filepath=storageRef.child("Folder").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            UploadTask uploadTask=filepath.putFile(uri);
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    try {
                        final File localFile=File.createTempFile("filename","pdf");
                        filepath.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                pdfView.fromFile(localFile).load();
                            }
                        }) ;

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

I am new to android programming. Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Check if the file exists before you try to load it. And check the size. What is the full path? And why do you create it as temp file first? You only need a file name/path.

Comment: @greenapps I am trying to store the uploaded file inside the local file so that I can display  the file in pdf view.

Comment: Your remark does not make sense. Please answer my questions. And show how you implemented suggestions.

Comment: I cannot write any specific file name since the user can upload any pdf file with whatever name they want.

Comment: Again your comment does not make sense. You could tell the full path of course.

Comment: Well I am not sure if I am doing the right thing. You can rectify me if I am wrong.

Comment: So what is localFile.getAbsolutePath()? And localFile.exists()?. And localFile.length()?